# Media Query doesn't initialize in browser's mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I didn't just resize the browser I used the developer tools under Chrome.

I made sure I had the proper meta tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And used max/min-width instead of -device-width.

The queries don't show up at all. But the local version works well. I'd rather not post the live version here because of the nature of the site itself but I'll try to give as much information as possible.

Comment: I use this @media (max-width: 480px)  and works. On which device you have tested?

Comment: Only on a China Android device. KitKat. 5.5 inch screen. I think it's 1280*720. And your suggestion still didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: If you use chrome in your phone, you can inspect the phone browser with chrome in your pc. Maybe in this way you can find what is the problem https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 1):

order can be important with media queries, one can be overriding another if you don't have them ordered properly

Comment: Ok I'll check this out. Would you have any idea though regarding the local version working well?